# C# Storing categories in a value - Bitmasks

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I am working on an application that have some categories. The aim is to store the categories in a value.
First, I choosed to store them in an int.
Categories : 0, 1, 2, 3...
Then I do a bitmask operation to find which category was selected.
But the problem is that I can't store more that 31 categories is this int.

Is there any way to make such system ? I don't want to go threw the unlimited number of categories but maybe over 64.
The target language is C# but any other solution could be fine.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If `int` is to small you can use `byte[]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [System.Collections.BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx), which is an arbitrary-length array of bits. You can do intersections (AND), unions (OR), and complements (NOT).

You can now haver more than 32 categories keyed by integers:

```
public static class Categories
{
   public const int Category1 = 1;
   public const int Category2 = 2;
    //...
   public const int Category3123 = 3123;
   public const int Max = 5000;
}

BitArray myBitset = new BitArray((int)Categories.Max);
myBitSet.Set(Categories.Category1);
myBitSet.Set(Categories.Category4);
```

I used ints rather than enums to avoid all the casts to int that are necessary when using BitArray, but obviously you could encapsulate these in a class that deals with categories.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer ! Is it possible to store a BitArray in a database ?

Comment: You'll have to extract the bits as an array of bytes:

    var array = new byte[(Categories.Max + 7)/8];
    x.CopyTo(array, 0);

then save the array of bytes to a BINARY or VARBINARY field.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I correctly understand your question so here are 2 answers:

If you want to categorize an object but it can hold **only one category** at a time you can perfectly choose just to store the category number in the int - no need for bitmasking.

If you want to store different flags/categories/options that should **all** be either true or false for a given object then you should go for a longer bitmask. An **array of bools** is a good idea - no need to do bit ops to get and set the values and I am pretty sure the compiler does it's best to optimize space usage (as you know a single bool variable is actually *one byte* but I assume that if you create many bool variables they will actually be stuffed insisde the least possible space.) Anyway you can always opt for your **own implementation** with long, which is 64 bits, or even BigInteger - unlimited number of digits, you just initially have to set it to 1*10^x where x is the number of the larges bit position you want to have access to.

Comment: The aim is to store multiple categories, so I think that the BitArray is fine like John said.

Answer (score 0):

If you define you categories like this:

```
public enum Categories
{
    Category1 = 0x0001,
    Category2 = 0x0002,
    Category3 = 0x0004,
    Category4 = 0x0008,
    Category5 = 0x000F,
    Category6 = 0x0010,
    Category7 = 0x0020,
    Category8 = 0x0040,
    // etc...
}
```

Then you can use them like this:

```
var myCategories = Categories.Category1 | Categories.Category4;

if(myCategories | Categories.Category1 > 0)
{
    // do something for category 1....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using bit masks here? Is there an overarching concern for storage efficiency? Otherwise just use a `HashSet` of your categories.

Conceptually a bit set and a conventional set container are identical, a bit set is just a particular implementation with special performance characteristics.