# Is It Possible to Use Hashcodes as a Bitmask to Efficiently Store/Track Collection Membership?

Tags: c#, .net, hashcode, hashset, bitmask

Currently I have a solution where I keep track of objects I am interested in by getting their hashcode via `Object.GetHashCode` and then storing them in a `HashSet<int>`.

However, I have also been learning about bitmasks and bitwise operations and I am quite intrigued by them.  [Here is a great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087162/c-sharp-storing-categories-in-a-value-bitmasks) that I found close to what I am looking to do.  However, I cannot seem to make this work efficiently for hash codes.

[There is also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585971/storing-multiple-values-via-bitmask-in-c-sharp), but it seems to deal with 5-bit numbers, when hash codes are `int`'s (32-bits).

I do get the `BitArray` solution (from the first referenced question) working, but it is not as fast as my current HashSet approach is. This is due to the sheer number of items in the `BitArray` that need to be created to account for all known hash codes (`int.MaxValue`).

Is there some a bitmask/bitwise operation I should consider in making this work with a `BitArray`?  Or have I totally gone off the beaten path here and should simply stick with my `HashSet<int>` solution?

Comment: fyi dont use gethashcode, collision can happen easily! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968753/probability-of-getting-a-duplicate-value-when-calling-gethashcode-on-strings

Comment: You should be storing *the objects themselves* in the `HashSet`, not storing their `GetHashCode` values.  By only storing the hashes you remove the ability of the `HashSet` to manage collisions.  As far as the rest of the question, it's based on the premise that the hash is unique for every object, but that's a false assumption, so you can't do that.  Just put the items in a `HashSet`.

Comment: @Servy that is a good point and you have made me reconsider my design here.  I was hoping to store information without having to create a strong-reference in memory to the object and also making it as fast as possible.  Sounds like I already found the solution (just making sure I did!).

Comment: @Mike-EEE You could create a weak reference to it, but to not reference it entirely you'd need to have it generate a value that's known to always be unique for that object, and that will never collide.  `GetHashCode` doesn't do that; it'd need to provide some other, stronger, form of hashing.

Comment: @Servy correct.  The problem (as I understand it) is that these objects can be structs as well, which don't apply for `WeakReference`, or at least with `WeakReference<T>`.  I will put more thought into this.

Comment: Thanky @Fredou and Servy (can't tag, sorry!) for your help!  I have figured out a solution and posted it as an answer.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed an instance of going off the beaten path, paired with a misunderstanding of references/memory management.  In my case I was using a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` object to store cached results from method calls on an instance.  I couldn't use a `ConditionalWeakTable` because there are at least three parts to a key:

1. The instance that contains the method where the results are being cached.
2. Said method.
3. Arguments being passed into the method.

If I used a `ConditionalWeakTable` I would have to create "yet another object" (class) that would require yet another allocation, but worse yet would not be referenced by anything (besides the `ConditionalWeakTable`) and would get garbage collected on the first pass (this is indeed [related to another open -- but now also solved -- question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846669/is-it-possible-to-use-conditionalweaktable-with-a-tuple-key-or-a-key-comprised)).

After much thought around this, I have realized that the answer does indeed lie in `ConditionalWeakTable`.  Rather than use the 3 items above as a key, the answer is to use a `Delegate` made up from parts 1 and 2, and then pair a `Dictionary` to that.

Or to put as a field initialization:

```
readonly ConditionalWeakTable<Delegate, Dictionary<object[], object>> cache = new ConditionalWeakTable<Delegate, Dictionary<object[], object>>();
```

(Also of note is the use of a [`StructuralEqualityComparer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609823/what-problem-does-istructuralequatable-and-istructuralcomparable-solve/5601068#5601068) with the above dictionary to make this work).

This of course does everything I want.  It will keep track of objects until the referenced object which contains the method (and from which the `Delegate` is comprised) is cleaned from memory.  At this point, the cached dictionary will also be released as well, clearing out all of its contents.